# Why does this insertBefore not create a dom element before and after the target div

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to write a new dom element before and after the target div.  This code only works for one or the other but not both.

```
function addElement () {

    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var newContent = document.createTextNode("This is a new text node.");
    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);

    var currentDiv = document.querySelector("#results");

    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv.nextSibling);
}

addElement();
```

Comment: you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert the same element in two places.

If you want to insert two elements, you need to create two elements.